# Problema en java con el metodo length(): The method length(String) is undefined for the type

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de sacar el length de una variable dentro de la clase data_format() y me sale el error mencionado en el titulo de la pregunta.

Imagino que la razón por la que me sale es porque no es hereditario el método, pero no se que tengo que hacer para poder calcular el length de la variable. Alguíen podría ayudarme?

```
public class codigo {
    public static void main(String[] args){        
        System.out.println("SSSS");
        String date = data_format();
        System.out.println(date);        
    }

    public static String data_format(){
        Calendar calendar_ = Calendar.getInstance();
        String DD = Integer.toString(calendar_.get(Calendar.DATE));

        int luzera_DD = length(DD);
        if (luzera_DD == 1){
            DD = '0' + DD;
        }
        return (DD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Para sacar el length del string debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma. `variableString.length()`. En tu caso `DD.length()`

Comment: Vaale, muchas gracias @Jacobo